# Neo4j failed to start on Windows 7

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j was working fine but today it failed to start. I tried to uninstall it and install it again and this is the error message that I got:

```
> bin\neo4j.bat install-service -verbose
VERBOSE: Neo4j Root is 'C:\Users\UserB\Documents\neo4j-community-3.1.4'
VERBOSE: Neo4j Server Type is 'Community'
VERBOSE: Neo4j Version is '3.1.4'
VERBOSE: Neo4j Database Mode is ''
WARNING: This command does not appear to be running with administrative rights.  Some commands may fail e.g. Start/Stop
VERBOSE: Install command specified
VERBOSE: Neo4j Windows Service Name is neo4j
VERBOSE: Java detected at 'C:\Devel\jdk18\jre\bin\java.exe'
VERBOSE: Executing C:\Devel\jdk18\jre\bin\java.exe -version
Invoke-Neo4j : Process with an Id of 2092428 is not running.
At line:1 char:261
+ try { Unblock-File -Path 'C:\Users\UserB\Documents\neo4j-community-3.1.4\bin\Neo4j-Management\*.*' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' } catch {};Import-Module 'C:\Users\UserB\Documents\neo4j-community-3.1.4\bin\Neo4j-Management.ps d1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j <<<<  install-service -verbose)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-N
```

I found that it might be because of a syntax error in `Merge-Neo4jJavaSettings.ps1` as it is explained [here](http://techqa.info/programming/question/39383023/neo4j-3.0.4-enterprise-trial-version-failed-to-start-in-windows). But I don't have the same code in that file so I couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: do you run it as administrator / from admin shell ?

Comment: Do I have to change the syntax and add something to my command line to run it as administrator?

Comment: "run as administrator" is available via ?? + right-clicking (alt or ctrl or shift).
BTW, v3.2 is available :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning line says you should run it with admin rights.
open the folder in explorer, then as I wrote, there is a combination with right click to get a contextual menu that proposes to open an admin shell.